# If $\mu$ is a measure on $X\times Y$, is there a measure $\mu_X$ on $X$ and $\mu_Y$ on $Y$ s.t. $\mu(A)=\int \mu_X(A^y)\mu_Y(dy)$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space and $X,Y$ two non-independent r.v. that have a joint distribution. I know that $$\mathbb P\{(X,Y)\in A\times B\}=\int_{B}\mathbb P\{X\in A\mid Y=y\}\mu_Y(dy),$$
where $\mu_Y$ is the measure induced by $Y$ on $\mathbb R$.

Is this theorem generalizable on an unspecified measure space $(X\times Y, \mu)$ ? i.e. is there a measure $\mu_X$ on $X$ and $\mu_Y$ on $Y$, s.t. $$\mu(A\times B)=\int_B \mu_X(A\times B^y)\mu_Y(dy)$$
where $A\times B^y=\{x\mid (x,y)\in A\times B\}$  ?

Comment: Note that this is not a generalization of the claim at the beginning of your question. The point is that the measure $P(X \in A \mid Y=y) =: P_y (A)$ *depends* on $y$, while in the second part of your question you want a measure$\mu_X$ which does not depend on any parameter.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is called disintegration of measure: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem